# Windows 10 Bluetooth cannot find my Sony MDR-XB950BT/B Headphones

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, headphones, a2dp

The cable that I used to connect my headphones to my laptop broke. I found it unreasonable to pay $55 for a new one, so I decided that trying to figure out how to pair them with my laptop would be easier and more cost efficient. For the past 6 days, I have been googling how to do it, with no luck yet. Here is what I've gathered so far:

My laptop has no trouble pairing with other devices. I'm confused to exactly what this is or how it works, but several forums have said that I need an A2DP profile to do so.

I can connect the headphones to my phone, using the app recommended by them (NFC Easy Connect.) My tablet however cannot find the device without the app.

When trying to download a Lenovo bluetooth adapter, it said that no bluetooth device was detected. ( https://gyazo.com/8fae27fd4791c2ef0254ed3d8964389d ) Under device manager, I have bluetooth devices listed under both the "Bluetooth" column and the "Network Adapters" column. ( https://gyazo.com/1a6f68efeec1fce13f7496975e87cacc ) I do not think this is the problem though, since my laptop can find any other bluetooth device easily.

I am really at a loss on what to do. The headphones are meant to connect to laptops with bluetooth adapters, yet it seems impossible. The Sony website says that if you search, it should be easily able to detect and pair with the devices. Any suggestions on what to do? I will update information on my computer or headphones if necessary. Thanks for any replies.

(I am currently running on a Lenovo Edge 2-in-1. )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Manual of your sony mdr-xb950bt headphones:

1. place unit 1 meter from bluetooth device
2. enter pairing mode by pressing POWER button for 7 seconds
3. when the device is detected, select MDR-XB950BT, if passkey asked for enter "0000"
4. make the bluetooth connection from the bluetooth device

With this said, you should maybe set the allow to find this computer setting to "ON" to be on the safe side.

I found the manual here [Sony Manuals for XB950BT](https://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/content/cnt-man/MDR-XB950BT/list)

Comment: I feel pretty stupid for not reading the manual. I guess reading really is fundamental.

Comment: :) and BTW it should be "0000" (missed one) just in case if you again skipped the manual and try to do it with my instructions ;)

Comment: @Zina Thank you very much. I'm wasted 2 hours for this issue without reading manual. Now everything is fine :)